# How to observe a broadcastReceiver's mutableLiveData variable?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm

I'm trying to observe a MutableLiveData from a broadcastReceiver class, but it doesn't work.

I send a notification, and I add an action on it that starts a pendingIntent. The pendingIntent send a broadcast to my NotificationReceiver class that extends BroadcastReceiver. It gets to the onReceive function, and changes a MutableLiveData.
In a different class I'm trying to observe this MutableLiveData but it works only for the first time, in the initialization part. However when the MutableLiveData changes in the NotificationReceiver "onRecieve" function, the observer doesn't work.

Creating the notification with an action

```
val intent = Intent(context, NotificationReceiver::class.java).apply {
    action = "ZOOM"
}

val pendingIntent: PendingIntent =
        PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0)

val notifyBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, Constants.PRIMARY_CHANNEL_ID)
        .setContentTitle(notificationTitle)
        .setContentText(notificationText)
        .setSmallIcon(notificationIcon)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .addAction(
                R.drawable.icon,
                "zoom",
                pendingIntent
        )

mNotifyManager?.notify(notificationID, notifyBuilder.build())
```

my NotificationReceiver class:

```
class NotificationReceiver: BroadcastReceiver() {
    var shouldZoom = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()

    init {
        shouldZoom.value = false
    }

    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        when (intent?.action) {
            "ZOOM" -> zoomLoaction()
        }
    }

    private fun zoomLoaction() {
        shouldZoom.value = true
    }
}
```

Observing in a fragment:

```
var notificationReceiver = NotificationReceiver()
notificationReceiver.shouldZoom.observe(this, Observer {
    if (it) {
        // Log
    }
})
```

Manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".NotificationReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="ZOOM" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: have you posted correct code because you have defined pendingIntent named PendingIntent and using notificationPendingIntent in notification build.

Comment: thanks for the correction, just fixed it now. though it is not the problem because it was correct in my code. @AmitTiwary